# Capistrano deploy using Passenger not changing release

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, passenger

I have a Rails app using a Virtual Ubuntu Server, Apache, Passenger, and Capistrano.

The first time I deployed the app with Capistrano I had set Passenger to select that first release with this code in httpd.conf file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName ndeavor.ameipro.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130306192753/public
 <Directory /opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130306192753/public>
   Allow from all
   Options -MultiViews
 </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And that started the correct 1st release of my Rails app.

Now, when I Cap Deploy, I would like Capistrano to automatically have Passenger launch the new release.

So, I uncommented these lines in deploy.rb

```
# If you are using Passenger mod_rails uncomment this:
  namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
 end
```

The new release was not started.  Should I remove the VirtualHost entry from the https.conf file?  Is there some step I'm missing?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When deploying with Capistrano, there is a symlink in your releases directory called current. Your document root should be pointed to the public directory at `myapp/releases/current/public`. Then, Capistrano updates the symlink on each deploy to point to the latest release.

Comment: Thanks for you help!  I made the change and restarted Apache.  But, now I'm getting Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /home/index on this server.

Comment: What is /home/index? Your httpd.conf file should include /opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/current/public for the document root. Not sure where /home/index comes from

Comment: I fixed it - there was another line in https.conf that needed the same myapp/releases/current/public.  It was # This should be changed to whatever you set DocumentRoot to.
#
<Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/current/public">